# how to do jooq multiple join and retrieve in a list

Tags: java, jooq

```
public List<DogModel> getDogData(DSLContext,dog_id) {
    final Optional<?> result = Optional.ofNullable(dContext.select(DogBreed.breed, DogProfile.name,DogProfile.tag_id)
        .from(DogProfile)
        .join(DogBreed)
        .on(DogProfile.tag_id.eq(DogBreed.tag_id))
        .join(Dog)
        .on(DogProfile.id.eq(Dog.id))
        .where(DogBreed.breed.isNotNull().and(DogBreed.breed.notEqual("")).and(Dog.id.eq(dog_id)))
        .fetch());

    //how to return the list of dog model?
}
```

Dog model has : breed, name and tag id

Answer (score 0):

This is a case for the [`RecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-execution/fetching/recordmapper/).

If your `DogModel` is a regular (or also JPA annotated) POJO, then it is quite likely that the `DefaultRecordMapper` will be able to automatically map the result records to your `DogModel` objects. Instead of calling `fetch()` on your query just call `fetchInto(DogModel.class)`. If this doesn't work as expected, you can use your own `RecordMapper` implementation.